# Download manager continues to send packets and uses up bandwidth

Tags: windows, download-manager

Recently I have realized my bandwidth for internet is getting full, even when I don't use internet. My firewall shows "bandwidth full".

So I install *Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4* and finally I think I found the problem

I am using *Internet Download Manager* and *FlashGot* for downloading. I understand when my file is finished or I click on the "pause" button, these download managers continue to
actually send packets. When this problem occurs, the firewall just shows my bandwidth and not which process caused the problem. I can however see from this from network monitor.

I just want to know if is this Windows problem or a virus?

I am sure it has nothing to do with the download manager because I try a lot of download managers and I have this problem with all of them. I don't have this problem when I download a file directly with the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Torrent part of these programs, it is possible that you are seeding even if you have selected pause.

I recommend trying to close these application all together, then monitor your bandwidth again.

It could possibly be a virus, but at this point, I find it very unlikely.